# Why are there strange Gmail accounts using my app in Google Play Closed Testing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, publishing

ive an app in Closed Testing (only a few emails in my tester list), but I noticed strange gmail accounts signing up for my app! I have checked that my app is not found in Google Play Store (except when logged into a tester emaiL). Should I be concerned? Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn’t a programming-related question but instead a support question about Google Play services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [article](https://medium.com/googleplaydev/google-play-expands-its-pre-launch-testing-capabilities-9b51a23077cf) by the Google Play Team, this is normal. The Google Play store does some automatic testing of each uploaded app. If it finds a Google Sign-In, it will use a test account to sign up / sign in for the app.

> Getting behind the sign in
>
> The developers of our imaginary app care about keeping their users’ data safe and secure, so the app uses custom login or Google Sign-In. When the crawler sees a Sign-In with Google button, it uses a Google account included on the test device. If your app doesn’t use Google Sign-In, you can configure the pre-launch report with a test account username and password that the crawler will enter when it encounters the login screen.